# Laravel pluck with paginate

Tags: laravel

So, I've a ERM with two database connected in a same laravel app.  I'm trying to pull up all the IDs with pluck which is working fine but not being able to paginate. For an instance,

```
        $newsTagSaved = NewsTag::latest()->pluck('post_id');
```

This works just as fine. But this pulls up way more information than I need. I'm looking for something like:

```
->pluck('id')->paginate(12);
```

This way I'm not loading data in ajax that I don't need since it will query unnecessary data on every ajax call.

Thank you!

Comment: try this:`$newsTagSaved = NewsTag::latest()->select('id')->paginate(12)`